# Fetch OAuth token from ebay api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, token, ebay-api

I'm developing a web application to to fetch data from 'https://api.ebay.com/sell/analytics/v1/traffic_report'

I've a ebay developer account with 
ClientId: MyClientId
ClientSecret: MyClientSecret
AppId: MyAppId

To achive this, I need a OAuth token

To get OAuth Token I do the following steps.

I browse the url bellow

https://signin.ebay.com/authorize?client_id=MyClientId&redirect_uri=RuName&response_type=code&state=analytics&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope%2Fsell.analytics.readonly

It goes to

https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?VAppJanessa&reqinput=reqinput - auto generate

after sign in   it redirects to 'Grant application access to MySiteDisplayName' page.

After I Agree it redirects to 'https://my_site.com/?state=analytics&code=code'
I've preapared a post request after collecting the code

I've executed the post request using POSTMAN  like bellow

Post URL: 'https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token'

**Headers**:

cache-control: no-cache

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Authorization: Basic Base64 value of 'MyClientId:MyClientSecret'

**Body**:

grant_type: authorization_code

redirect_uri: RuName

code: code returned from previous request

After post request I've got the result

{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "the provided authorization grant code is invalid or was issued to another client"
}

Please tell me what is missing or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like clientId and appId you are sending don't match each other, probably one is a production one and another being a developer one. Happened with me once.

If there are multiple apps being registered, each with its own appId under the same clientId, many times the client Secret Gets missed. Try checking the correct combination of all three.

Comment: clientId and appId are the same thing

Comment: Not sure about ebay but in Azure clientId is the company and appId is specific app

Comment: @Debashis I cam getting the same error. Did you manage to solve and share your solutions.